# Prove that a pointwise converging sequence, bounded in $L^p$, converge uniformly in $L^q$, using Egorov's theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence

> Let $p > 1$, $E$ be a measurable subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with finite
> Lebesgue measure $\mu$, $\{f_n\}_{n\in N}$ be a sequence of measurable
> functions $f_n : E → \mathbb{R}$, bounded in $L^p(E)$, and pointwise converging to $f : E → \mathbb{R}$.
>
> Prove that $\{f_n\}_{n∈N}$ converges to $f$ in
> $L^q(E)$ for all $q ∈(1, p)$.

All the hypothesis of Egorov's theorem are satisfied, then $\forallε > 0$  $\exists N_ε ⊆ Ω$ measurable such that $\mu(N_ε) ≤ ε$ and such that the sequence $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$ in $Ω \setminus N_ε$.

Any hint on how to start the exercise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a hint on how to start. Use Egorov's theorem to split the domain into two parts, one with $\epsilon$ measure on which convergence is bad, and one with the majority of the measure on which convergence is good. Then bound the total $q$-norm of the difference of the sequence from the limit by bounding the $q$-norm of the difference on each of these sets.

Comment: Thanks. I would do this: since the sequence converge almost everywhere, take the set $N_\epsilon$ of measure zero where the seq does not converge, and $E\setminus N_\epsilon$ where the seq converge. Then from what you wrote I got that we have to bound $||f_n-f||_{L^q(E)}$ with $||f_n-f||_{L^q(N_\epsilon)}+||f_n-f||_{L^q(E\setminus N_\epsilon)}$. But the first norm is infinite because on $N_\epsilon$ the sequence does not converge. Do we need to change the choice of the two sets?

Comment: Could you say what it the $L^q$ norm of $f_n-f$ on the set $E\setminus N_\varepsilon$ ?